# How to connect Mysql Docker to other docker in Dockerfile?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using these Docker commands:

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 magentonet
docker run -d --name mysql -p 3306:3306 --net magentonet --ip 172.18.0.23 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=magepass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mySchema mysql:5
docker build -t magento-bdd .
docker run --net magentonet --ip 172.18.0.22 -d magento-bdd
```

When the command `docker build -t magento-bdd .` runs, I have this RUN command in there:

```
mysql --host=172.18.0.23 --user=root --password=magepass -e "create database magentodb; create user magentouser@localhost; grant all privileges on magentodb.* to 'magentouser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'magentopass'; flush privileges;"
```

The problem I face now, is that the command ends with `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.18.0.23' (110)`

This kinda makes sense because I haven't connected the container to the network yet (this will happen in the `run` command.

How can I already store something in the database of the previous build Docker from the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

`docker build` runs each instruction in an intermediate, temporary container, and there's no way to connect that container to your Docker network. So you can't make use of the `mysql` container when you build a new image.

Instead I'd look at building a custom database image first, with a Dockerfile that starts `FROM mysql` and runs the database creation scripts. Then you'd have a database image that's already set up, which you can run and connect to your app.